# Sub total and total auto compute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just need the following:

```
subtotal = sum(product1,product2)
 total = sum(subtotal,vat)
```

from code

```
 $('input').keyup(function(){
    var v = this.value, el = $(this);
    if(!isNaN(v)){
        var ov = el.siblings('.valid').val();        
        el.siblings().last().val(v*ov);
        $(this).removeClass('nope').trigger('totalChange');
    } else {
       $(this).addClass('nope');
    }
});

$(document).on('totalChange', function(){
    var val1 = parseFloat($('#vat_zero_re').val(), 10);
    var val2 = parseFloat($('#ve_subtotal').val(), 10);
    $('#total').val(val1+val2);
});
```

source code : http://jsfiddle.net/4c0epamc/

Comment: may i know, whats your problem? what you have get?

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/4c0epamc/1/) what you want???in your fiddle you havent included jquery..

Comment: i need an output of subtotal = product1 + product2

Comment: thank you so much @Lal ^_^ your an angel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/4c0epamc/3/)

**Javascript**

```
$('input').keyup(function(){

    var v = this.value, el = $(this);
    if(!isNaN(v)){
        var ov = el.siblings('.valid').val();        
        el.siblings().last().val(v*ov);
        $(this).removeClass('nope').trigger('totalChange');
    } else {
       $(this).addClass('nope');
    }
});

$(document).on('totalChange', function(){
    var valx=parseFloat($('#peza_locator').val(), 10);
    var valy = parseFloat($('#peza_facilities').val(), 10);
    $('#ve_subtotal').val(valx+valy);
    var val1 = parseFloat($('#vat_zero_re').val(), 10);
    var val2 = parseFloat($('#ve_subtotal').val(), 10);
    $('#total').val(val1+val2);
});
```

In the fiddle that you specified no jquery was linked and in my fiddle to calculate the sub total i used 2 new variables named valx and valy.. check it..

Comment: Sir @Lal follow up question. if I apply bootstrap(modal) It wont work?

Comment: It will as this is javascript